# Why is the $\operatorname{GL}_n$ character variety "cohomologically" the product of the $\operatorname{PGL}_n$ character variety and a torus?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, character-varieties

$\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}\def\GL{\operatorname{GL}}$This question is about an assertion in [Mixed Hodge polynomials of character varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612668), by Hausel and Rodriguez-Villegas. Fix positive integers $g$ and $n$ and let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity.

Let
$$H = \left\{ (A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_g, B_1, B_2, \ldots, B_g) \in \GL_n^{2g}(\CC) : \prod_{i=1}^g (A_i B_i A_i^{-1} B_i^{-1}) = \zeta \cdot\mathrm{Id}_n \right\}.$$
Let $M = H/{\GL_n(\CC)}$, acting by conjugation, and let $\tilde{M} = (\CC^{\ast})^{2g} \backslash M$ acting by rescaling the $A_i$ and $B_i$.

At the top of page 4, Hausel and Rodriguez-Villegas say that $M$ is "cohomologically a product" of $(\CC^{\ast})^{2g}$ and $\tilde{M}$ which I interpret to mean that, although the $(\CC^{\ast})^{2g}$-bundle $M \to \tilde{M}$ may not be trivial, we nonetheless have
$$H^{\ast}(M, \ZZ) \cong H^{\ast}(\tilde{M}, \ZZ) \otimes_{\ZZ} H^{\ast}((\CC^{\ast})^{2g}, \ZZ).$$
Conveniently, $H^{\ast}((\CC^{\ast})^{2g}, \ZZ)$ is torsion free, so there are no $\operatorname{Tor}_1$ terms in Künneth.

This is not obvious to me. Why is it true? For what more general versions of character varieties is it true?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to keep reading to the proof of Theorem 2.2.12.

The main point is that the $PGL_n$-character variety $\tilde{\mathcal{M}}_n/\mathbb{C}$ is both a quotient by a torus $\mathcal{M}_1/\mathbb{C}\cong (\mathbb{C}^*)^{2g}$ of the $GL_n$-character $\mathcal{M}_n/\mathbb{C}$ and also a quotient of a finite group $\mu_n^{2g}$ of the $SL_n$-character variety $\mathcal{M}^\prime_n/\mathbb{C}$ and the action of a finite group gives the invariant part in cohomology in one factor while trivial in the other (since it is a torus).

Thus, quoting the proof of Theorem 2.2.12, we have: \begin{eqnarray*}H^∗(\mathcal{M}_n/\mathbb{C}) &=&(H^∗(\mathcal{M}^\prime_n/\mathbb{C}\times \mathcal{M}_1/\mathbb{C}))^{\mu_n^{2g}}\\ &=& H^∗(\mathcal{M}^{\prime}_n
/\mathbb{C})^{\mu_n^{2g}}\otimes H^∗(\mathcal{M}_1/\mathbb{C})\\ &=& H^∗(\tilde{\mathcal{M}}_n/\mathbb{C})\otimes H^∗(\mathcal{M}_1/\mathbb{C}).\end{eqnarray*}

This phenomenon occurs for other character varieties too.

For example, for free groups, see Theorem 2.4 in my paper with Florentino *[Singularities of free group character varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4720)*.  Note that the theorem is stated for $GL_n$ and $SL_n$ but it generalizes to connected reductive $G$ and its derived subgroup $DG$.

More generally, for $G\cong DG\times_F T$ (central isogeny theorem for connected complex reductive $G$), we have:
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm{Hom}^0(\Gamma,G)&\cong&\mathrm{Hom}^0(\Gamma,DG \times T)/\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,F)\\
             &\cong&(\mathrm{Hom}^0(\Gamma,DG) \times \mathrm{Hom}^0(\Gamma,T))/\mathrm{Hom}'(\Gamma,F), 
\end{eqnarray*}$$
by Prop. 5(1) in *[G-Character varieties for G=SO(n,C) and other not simply connected groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.7181)* by Sikora.  Note that the superscript $0$ denotes the connected component of the trivial representation and $\mathrm{Hom}'(\Gamma,F)$ denotes the subgroup of $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,F)$ mapping $\mathrm{Hom}^0(\Gamma,DG \times T)$ to itself.  This then gives a similar decomposition for corresponding components of the character varieties by quotienting by $PG$ (since $F$ is central and so commutes with the conjugation action).

The above paragraph is quoted from my paper with Sikora *[Varieties of Characters](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02164)*.

See also my paper with Ramras *[Covering spaces of character varieties](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.0781)* for related theorems.  In particular, for "exponent canceling" groups we can remove the superscript $0$ above (for some $G$).  Examples of exponent-canceling groups are free groups, surface groups, free abelian groups, and RAAGs.

Comment: I guess another way to say this is that the way passing to a $\mathbb G_m$-bundle changes the cohomology is determined by its Chern class, and here all $2g$ $\mathbb G_m$-bundles are $n$-torsion and so their Chern classes are rationally trivial.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidESpeyer You are very welcome :)  Feel free to email too if you want to chat about character varieties.